# Retrieve data from an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm, dosbox

So, basically I just want to display the first data from array which is userbalanceIndex1 from userbalanceIndex.

But I get an error which is

> DEMO.ASM(29): Out of memory
> 29 line: mov bl,(userbalanceIndex +1)

Here is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100H
.data
    userbalanceIndex db usrbalance1, usrbalance2, usrbalance3, usrbalance4
    usrbalance1 Db 1
    usrbalance2 Db 9
    usrbalance3 Db 6
    usrbalance4 Db 0

.code


OUTPUT MACRO DIGIT
 MOV AH, 02H
 MOV DL, DIGIT
 INT 21H
ENDM

main proc
    MOV AX,@DATA 
    MOV DS,AX

    mov al, userbalanceIndex
    mov cx, 0
    a:  
        inc userbalanceIndex
        mov bl, （userbalanceIndex + 1）
        loop a
        
    OUTPUT bl
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: You need to use registers to index an array; x86 doesn't have memory-indirect addressing modes.  (And the syntax uses `[]` not `()`.)  Also not clear why you'd want to increment the first byte of a byte-array (`inc userbalanceIndex`).

Comment: The tags don't make sense here.  [emu8086] is a stand-alone assembler / simulator / debugger / IDE.  If you're using it, you aren't using [dosbox], and vice verse.  Also, DOSBox is an environment you can run other things in, not an assembler itself, so unless you're asking about special things about its implementation of BIOS calls or hardware emulation or something, it's just something you should mention in the question body, not tag.  Relevant tags could be [tasm] or [nasm] if you're using that inside DOSBox.